# Angular differential builds and schematics?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using AOT, and I have a dependency on `package.json` that causes some issues on IE, it brakes the whole application.

**Reproducing issue steps (Angular 8)**

```
1. ng new angular-tour-of-heroes
2. npm install peerjs
3. ng serve --aot 
4. open the application using Chrome
5. open application using Internet Explorer - You can see in the console an error,
   and the fact the app breaks.
```

The idea is to use the schematics to create pre-processing tasks that allow you to auto-configuration before running the final build path for each version. It means that I have run two commands, one for ES2015 build and the other for ES5 build. But I suppose that it's not a problem because ES5 build would be created only for a real deployment, but ES2015 for each day development.

https://angular.io/guide/schematics-authoring
https://angular.io/guide/deployment#differential-loading

Did anyone achieve this before? Do you have a working example?

**Update 1**
Updating Angular 8 to Angular 9, solved the issue, the app doesn't crash anymore, therefore in Angular 9, the issue doesn't reproduce.

**Still, the question remains, how do you obtain and serve two different builds with two different package.json and without a component file in the build without one of the packages?**

Comment: Maybe it's worth looking at webpack config and make some configuration there?

Comment: issues on IE are not unusual. Whats your use case? Which IE Version is affected?

Comment: @nologin IE 11. But the idea is to have differential builds, with or without issue :)

Comment: You have to enable pollyfill to support IE. https://angular.io/guide/browser-support